# How many metabolites are in the metabolome of (almost) all eucaryotic cells?

Tags: molecular-biology, statistics, metabolomics

Which [small biomolecules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_molecule) (up to the size of amino acids) are present in (almost) **every** eucaryotic cell and thus part of its biochemical network, constantly and inevitably being produced and metabolized?

Is there either a comprehensive list (e.g. being a sublist of [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_biomolecules)) or at least a number: How many are there (roughly)?

To ask it differently: How many small molecules are in the [metabolome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolome) of (almost) all eucaryotic cells?

Side question: Does the famous [Metabolic Pathways poster](http://biochemical-pathways.com/#/map/1) contain all of them, or which percentage (roughly)?